# Microsoft Azure: There was an error while creating data connection 'SQL data connection'. Deployment to resource group failed

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create an Android Mobile app via the Azure app service and while doing so, I am trying to create a database, but I am getting the error 'there was an error while creating data connection 'SQL data connection'. Deployment to resource group failed'. Please help as soon as possible.
$[image]

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, no? You had a problem connecting to the SQL Server instance you were trying to deploy the database to. Check your connection settings and check whether the server is reachable from your environment.

Comment: My colleague was able to create the database for the same server with his login. So does is it mean there is some issue with my Azure profile? We both are part of Bizspark subscription.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to server limit exceeding the quote associated with your account. Under all resources, check if there's a new SQL server created with a random name- you will need to delete that. Attempt to create again.

(just done- it worked!)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the exact issue.
*First time it failed giving the error - Data Connection Creation Error..!*
When Configuring for the **first time** it didn't work for me.
i.e.,

- Creating a Database
- Creating a New Server
- Entering Server Admin Login
- Entering Server Admin Password

I've noted down all the above information.

Tried Second time setting up the Connection String with the above details **IT WORKED.**

Hope this information helps.